# Why is this simple code giving an error?

Tags: javascript

```
var d = new Date();
var day;
switch (d.getDay()) {
    case 0 :
      day = "Sunday";
      break;
    case 1 :
      day = "Monday";
      break;
    case 2 :
      day = "Tuesday";
      break;
    case 3 :
      day = "Wednesday";
      break;
    case 4 :
      day = "Thursday";
      break;
    case 5 :
      day = "Friday";
      break;
    default :
      day = "Saturday";
  }

 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Today is : " ;
```

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: This code seems to work for me - I get an "Monday" in the `day` variable.

Comment: Provided that `#demo` exists, `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Today is : " + day;`

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is `document.getElementById("demo")` returns undefined.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at myscript.js:27   #copied from console i.e. the last line

Comment: See the comment above from @Amy.  That element doesn't exist when you try to set the innerHTML property.

Comment: @Archer - Your edit actually removes the "issue" that the OP is talking about (missing HTML element) - I've rolled back your edit FYI.

Comment: Include your HTML.

Comment: @Lix - fair play.  At the time it didn't and I didn't want to introduce an error so I added the element :p

Comment: I have used the demo id in the html file and saved this javascript file seperately

Comment: But *where* in the HTML are you referencing the js file? Before or after the element with that ID?

Comment: Probably a case of needing to wait for the DOM to load before you modify it.  Put the script tags at the bottom of the page - last thing inside the body tag.

Comment: @ Gerardo Furtado after the element with the id

Answer (score -1):

Add HTML and missing `day` and append at the end before assignment

```js
var d = new Date();
var day;
switch (d.getDay()) {
  case 0:
    day = "Sunday";
    break;
  case 1:
    day = "Monday";
    break;
  case 2:
    day = "Tuesday";
    break;
  case 3:
    day = "Wednesday";
    break;
  case 4:
    day = "Thursday";
    break;
  case 5:
    day = "Friday";
    break;
  default:
    day = "Saturday";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Today is : " + day;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: downvote for a valid solution without mention of what's wrong and what could be the improvement to the answer, not helping anyone.